# How can I leftclick on google chrome with .bat file

Tags: batch-file

Okay.I want to do a little app thing, and it sounds like this:

```
@echo off
CLS
start https://www.youtube.com/
timeout 4
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
@echo off
CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"
rem Open the browser here
goto :EOF
@end
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("{K}");
>nul
```

It basically starts a video, when you open the file, runs in the background and presses K (my attempt to solve the problem), and then I want the video to automaticaly start.
P.S.I want to use .bat, not any other extension or program.
So:
How can I make the tab to open, and the video to automaticaly play?

Comment: See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Better try with phantom.js (https://phantomjs.org/) or seleniun (https://selenium.dev/) depending on if you want headless or visible browser.

Comment: For some time by now the YouTube platform changed the way to play the video playlists, forcing the user to click on the play button after some time in while, even with the music going, it’ll force it. If you need an script for this, let me know. I can create a macro to press the play button after some time.

Comment: @ItWasn'tMe Any help will do. I prefer to have everything in that .bat file

Comment: Just save as file.bat this is hybrid bat

Comment: I don’t know any method/command in bat that can use/send keys to GUI in the actual windows versions, so, only VBS/Powershell or, external executable.

Comment: BTW, only save as **`some_name.bat`** and run. The code is hybrid, but run and name is **`file.bat`**, or **`file.cmd`**.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is some kind of duplicate question here, anyway, I suggest using vbs to get this result.

**Obs.:**  Take a time to see the link video about **`SendKeys/VBS`**

```bat
<!-- :
@echo off && mode 50,03 && title <nul && title .\%~nx0 
start /d  "c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\" chrome.exe -new-tab "www.youtube.com/watch?v=BISQwNjP2NE"
%__APPDIR__%wScript.exe "%~dpnx0?.wsf" && goto :EOF
--> <job> <script language = "vbscript">
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.AppActivate "chrome"
WScript.Sleep 4000 
objShell.SendKeys " "           ' use space (charater) to play/pause 
'objShell.SendKeys ("+{F10}")    left click | in your question, the  
'objShell.SendKeys "{DOWN}"      left click | left click is not works
'objShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"     left click | for play the video
</script></job>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this in powershell:

```
@Echo Off
start  /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\" chrome.exe new-tab "www.youtube.com/watch?v=BISQwNjP2NE"
powershell -command "& {$wsh = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell; $wsh.AppActivate("Chrome"); Start-Sleep -Seconds 5; $wsh.Sendkeys(" "); $wsh.Sendkeys("+{F10}"); $wsh.Sendkeys("{DOWN}"); $wsh.Sendkeys("{ENTER}")}"
Exit /b
```

Thanks @It wasn't me for classic idea.